Why does const Type&& not cast to Type&&?
I know these two qualifiers are orthogonal, but this creates some weird problems.
Basically, I tried to move-construct a pair of <const T, T> from other pair&& of same type, but got bamboozled as that constructor got ill-formed :(
#include <iostream>

struct Special {
    int x = 0;
    explicit Special(int x): x(x) {}
    Special(const Special&) = delete;
    Special& operator=(const Special&) = delete;
    
    Special(Special&&) = default;
    Special& operator=(Special&&) = default;
};

struct NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible {
    Special x;

    NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible() = delete;
    NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible(const NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible&) = delete;
    NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible& operator=(const NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible&) = delete;

    NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible(Special&& x): x(std::move(x)) {}
    NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible(NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible&&) = default;
    NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible& operator=(NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible&&) = default;

    bool operator==(const NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible& other) const {
        return x.x == other.x.x;
    }
};

int main() {
    using NodeType = std::pair<const NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible, NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible>;
    NodeType a(Special(0), Special(1));
    NodeType b(std::move(a));
    return 0;
}

Error message:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:315:17: note: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible; _T2 = NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  315 |       constexpr pair(pair&&) = default;         ///< Move constructor

/home/bibaboba/CLionProjects/untitled4/main.cpp:32:28: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible; _T2 = NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible]’
   32 |     NodeType b(std::move(a));

Do I really have to dissolve the pair to move it, or is there any way to avoid it?

Always post complete error along with your question.

No need of pair to reproduce the issue, just const NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible Demo.

And moving a const object results in copying (unless constructor taking (const Object&&) is defined (but even then, internal cannot really move anything)).

@Jarod42 well, this is not quite the issue, I know everything is defined and what I get from moving the "const T" is "const T&&", but what we get is need for dissolving the pair and const-casting its elements to actually move it, and the problem could scope to more complex classes...

"Why does const Type&& not cast to Type&&?" because that will cast away CV qualifiers which is very necessary to avoid. If your class has a ctor which takes const Type&&, the compiler won’t delegate to copy ctor. The delegation is because it is the best option to invoke. But in your case, copy ctor is also deleted.

Moving a const T give a const T&&, and selected constructor is const T& which is deleted. And "dissolving" the pair doesn't solve anything Demo...

std::move is simply a cast that returns an xvalue expression. Expecting it to cast away const is a bit of an over stretch.
std::move will cast an object of const Type to const Type&&. That’s all it does.

basically, I tried to move-construct a pair of <const T, T> from other pair&& of same type, but got bamboozled as that constructor got ill-formed.

The ctor didn’t get ill formed. The ctor just doesn’t exist and the ctor the compiler resorted to was deleted hence the compiler got stuck and decided to throw errors.
You can choose to either provide a const Type&& ctor (not my best recommendation) or cast away const before std::move.

Casting away const brings its own set of problems, not least of which would be undefined behavior.

yup, but it also sounds painful as casting away every const qualifier is quite a lot of effort for the sake of just moving the class... the reason I put const qualifier on member was everything but disabling the move ctor:( and just moving the pair then expands to :   NodeType b(std::move(const_cast<NeitherDefaultNorCopyConstructible&>(a.first)), std::move(a.second));
wish there was a way to do it quicker and less heavy for a line of code

@MarkRansom b will return the CV.

I’m sorry @RiabovVladimir but moving a const variable is a red flag to begin with.

@ChukwujiobiCanon depends on the situation... mine is nodes in unordered_map: the key should be const as it cannot be modified, but there should be nothing wrong with moving it (the only place where it`s moved is inserting a new node taken as a pair by rvalue). then there is no proper way to construct the node but to move it, afaik...?

@RiabovVladimir But moving an object modifies the source object. If you get a key as a const reference out of any standard library map, you should never const_cast to move it away, this is (at least in the general case) undefined behavior. You always need to perform a copy in that case. (Though you only need to copy the key, not the value, that can be moved.) If you can't copy the type used as the key, then that type shouldn't be used as a key in the map.

@RiabovVladimir: std::map<K,V>::extract might interest you.
